# Django Test - Send Array of Arrays containing Integer

Tags: django, rest, api, testing, frameworks

currently i am trying to send an array of arrays containing integers to my rest api, this is part of my test:

```
res = self.client.post(
    '/data',
    {
        'data': [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6]
        ]
    }
)
```

In my serializer i try to print the data:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    print(self.context['request'].data)
    print(self.context['request'].data['data'])
```

But i just get:

```
<QueryDict: {'data': ['[1, 2, 3]', '[4, 5, 6]']}>
[4, 5, 6]
```

Expected:

```
{'data': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

How can this be?

Did i send the wrong format or did i access the json the wrong way...?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your serializer, add the following field:

```
data = serializers.JSONField()
```

There's no point in accessing `self.context['request'].data` in your serializer in your scenario. Instead you should be accessing `validated_data`. After adding the `JSONField`, access your data field through `validated_data` and you should find a list of lists.

```
validated_data["data"]
```

Comment: to be exactly it prints: validated_data {'data': [4, 5, 6]}

Comment: Can you make sure that you're sending it form postman correctly? Also, have you added the `JSONField()` ?

Comment: oh yea i forgot to specify the content_type and now it prints correctly..